# How to aggregate a certain amount of rows then compare to a user specified time

Tags: mysql

Essentially, I am looking to aggregate a column that uses time data type "00:00:00". I eventually want to compare this value to a user entered time value, for example "00:15:00". The user only has 15 minutes available. Then using a select query would generate a list of specific tasks that equal less than or equal to that time. The amount of tasks won't be predetermined but selected based on options a user chooses from a form before generating the list. Each task is a different duration stored as "00:00:00".

```
SELECT name AS Name, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(totalduration))) as total
FROM task 
WHERE ....
GROUP BY ...
HAVING SUM(totalduration) < CAST('00:15:00' AS time);
```

The where and group by clauses are not relevant as they contain other filtering specifications.

the totalduration column in my database is the time it takes each task to be completed in full. For example, doing laundry may take "01:20:00" including washing/drying and the time it takes to change into dryer from washer. Another task such as loading dishwasher could take "00:05:00".

| Task | totalduration |
| --- | --- |
| Laundry | '00:01:20' |
| Loading dw | '00:05:00' |
| Taking out trash | '00:01:00' |

I want to be able to aggregate all the durations(times) in this column that could add up to possibly fit within the time that the user selects (15 minutes in this example). I want to return the tasks that could be done within the allotted time. For example, the user only has 15 minutes to spare, they obviously can't do laundry but can load the dishwasher + whatever other tasks add up to 15 minutes or just under.